# Can I access FFPlay.exe's STDIN in order to emulate a 'q' keypress?

Tags: ffmpeg, stdin, winapi

I am writing a Win32 program that launches ffplay.exe. I would like to have my program send a quit message ('q') but cannot get ffplay to respond. I am using CreatePipe() to initialize read/write handles that are used by CreateProcess(), which launches ffplay.exe. Should I be able to make this work? If I start ffplay manually from a command line, pressing 'q' works fine. I would like to emulate that with my Win32 program. To test my code, I substituted ffplay.exe with another console application that prompts the user for input, and it responds as expected.

Comment: and from that thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview

Comment: I haven't tried SendInput -- I will do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

FFplay is not reading from `stdin`, they are reading keyboard events using the SDL gaming library ([see source](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/blob/HEAD:/fftools/ffplay.c#l3279)), so trying to send input to stdin is likely not going to work.

As an alternative, you have a handle to the process, could you not just terminate the process, rather than trying to send the application input to shut itself down?

Comment: Thanks for this info; very helpful. Yes, I have been calling TerminateProcess() to kill it, but have been spooked by the documentation that warns against using it since it doesn't notify DLLs (I think that's what I read). It sounds like that's my only real option?